# $x^x$ Derivative and Integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have evaluated $\frac{d}{dx} x^x$ to be $x^x \left( log(x) + 1 \right)$ is that correct? Furthermore, what is $\int x^x dx$? Is that even possible? If not, why?

Comment: Why don't you search for the integral (as I did), and check your derivative with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex+derivative&lk=4&num=1) (as I did)? Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Ok, so I see that the derivative is correct, but Wolfram gives a very complicated solution to the antiderivative. How is that found?

Comment: WolframAlpha states: "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions". It then gives a series expansion which is an approximation to the answer.

Comment: You're correct, I didn't see that it was an approximation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed form for the antiderivative, but for a definite integral there is [the sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream):

$$ \int_0^1 x^x\; dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-n} $$

Comment: The irresistible urge to post one-line answers to 10x duplicate questions...

Comment: @NormalHuman Why did someone have the urge to down vote a perfectly good answer?  It is not the respondent's responsibility to comb through the archaic categorization of answers before proceeding to help.  What is this perverse delight that some take for posting a comment such as yours?  +1 to neutralize the absurdity!

Comment: @Rbert Israel. Proving that formula for $\int^1_0 x^x $ was a Putnam Competition problem, one of the easier ones.

Comment: Hi Robert Israel ! Look at this : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function